# Statistics for mse: visitors before the first answer and answer rate per tag

Tags: discussion, answers, statistics

I am interested in some statistical information about the *math.stackexchange* website. Especially these two:

> What is the average number of visitors of a question before it receives the  first answer?
>
> What are the average answer rates per Tag?

Comment: [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) might be useful for stuff like this, for example [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/4899/answer-rate-on-tags). But I doubt it is possible to find statistics about number of views before the first answer.

Comment: @MartinSleziak interesting. thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can see answer rates per tag by going to the tag page, and looking for the "top users" link; for example, the [calculus tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/calculus/topusers) has an answer rate of about 90%.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange [does not store views with timestamps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120779/chart-statistics-views-votes-favorites-versus-time-and-revisions#comment319685_120779); each new view simply increments the view counter. (The way that views are measured excludes frequent reloads  by the same user.) However, you can find the distribution of [**time** before first answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12131/147263).

The answer rate by tag can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10362/147263); although the data is from last year, the pattern has not changed much. The query used there takes the SE definition of *answered* as "has an answer that is either accepted or has positive score".

My observations suggest that on this site, the majority of questions with only a zero-score answer are in fact satisfactorily answered. So I [forked the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/201210/questions-with-no-answers-by-tag) and obtained the number of questions by tag, with (blue) and without (red) answers below:

[image: no answer]

There are 10 tags in which more than 20% of questions have no answer:

1. [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)   $26.8\%$
2. [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods)  $25.08\%$
3. [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry) $24.82\%$
4. [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde)    $24.65\%$
5. [algebraic-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-topology) $23.27\%$
6. [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry)  $22.9\%$
7. [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)  $22.82\%$
8. [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions)  $20.93\%$
9. [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) $20.58\%$
10. [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) $20.4\%$

Comment: The top two lines suggest that askers of such questions are insufficiently aware of [scicomp.se]